# Building a SPA with react on top of MVC Routes

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, react-router, single-page-application

I have an API that has routes managed by MVC.
On top of that i want to build a SPA with react.
However the routes I build from inside my react app cannot be reached, i get an 404 from ISS, here us a stub from my code.

```
export default class Layout extends React.Component {
render() {
   <div> 
     <Router history={ hashHistory }>
       <Route path="/" component={ Home } >
         <Route path="login" component={ Login } />
       </Route>
     </Router>
   <div>
}
```

When I execute this code as a standalone whithout the backend, it works flawlessly.
Is there a way to tell MVC to render reacts routes for a set url, let's say "/app/*".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can try react.net

Comment: @Clément Péau did you find a solution?

Comment: @Sag1v Sadly not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As i mentioned in my comment, i may have a solution that can fit your needs.
This solution requires an `MVC` `Controller` and a relevant `MapRoute()`.
The general idea is to deliver the `index.html` page via `MVC` using a `controller` and `cshtml` and configure on `react-router` a `basename` when creating `browserHistory`.
The **key** here is that the `basename` value must contain the entire path (without the domain) up to the `controller` name.
for example:
given this `controller`:

```
public class ReactController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

and `cshtml`:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>app name</title>
    <link href="path/to/file.css/if/needed" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="path/to/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and `routeMap`:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "reactApp",
        url: "react/{*pathInfo}",
        defaults: new { controller = "React", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Now, lets say your app is published under `http://example.org/appName/`
then you'll need to make sure react-router won't delete the `"appName"` portion of the URL when changing it.
for example, if you're in the *Home Page* - `http://example.org/appName/home`
and you move to the *About Page*, you want `react-router` to keep the `"appName"`
like so: `http://example.org/appName/react/about`
and not like so `http://example.org/about`.

Although this will work just fine as you're not posting this URL back to the server, you will face a problem when you will try to go directly to the "About" page. the server will return a 404 when you send the request with this URL: `http://example.org/about/`
instead of this one: `http://example.org/appName/react/about`.

My soulution to this problem is to pass `react-router` a `basename` that includes the `appName` + sub folders (if any) + the controller name.

I'm using `useRouterHistory` and creating the `browserHistory` instead of `import` it from  `react-router`

```
const browserHistory = useRouterHistory(createHistory)({ 
  basename: appName
});
```

the `appName` variable is as follow:

```
const controller = "/react";
const pathName = window.location.pathname;
const appName = pathName.substring(0,pathName.indexOf(controller) + controller.length);
```

This can be refactored as a function but basically it gets the `pathname` up to the controller name (as a convention with your MVC app) including the controller name.
that way `react-router` will keep this path on every URL change.
In our case `"appName/react"`.

Comment: I just saw that I updated without thanking you. But your solution was working for me and greatly appreciated, so thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed react routing in ASP.NET + React SPA solution (.NET 5.0) by adding `exact path` instead of `path` for react-router-dom.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is using the [basename property of BrowserRouter](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter) in App.sjx:

```
...
import {
    BrowserRouter,
    Switch,
    Route
} from "react-router-dom";
...

const App = () => {
    const siteName = window.location.pathname.split("/")[1];
    return (
<BrowserRouter basename={`/${siteName}/React`}>
  <div>
   <Header />
   <Switch>                       
    <Route path="/users">
     <Users />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/map">
      <MapPage />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/">
     <HomePage />
    </Route>
   </Switch>
   <Footer />
   </div>
</BrowserRouter>
 );
}
export default App;
```